# How do I convert a check to words that includes the decimal position as well

Tags: java, arrays, string, currency

I have been given an assignment to write a method that takes a monetary value less than $1000.00 and writes the word equivalent of that amount.  This amount needs to include the part after the decimal as well (essentially the change part of the amount).
i.e.

```
Enter·check·amount:567.89↵
five·hundred·sixty·seven·and·89/100↵
```

I see that the topic has been covered numerous times but I can't seem to find any information on what I'm requesting. I am new to this (4 weeks) so forgive me if I'm asking the wrong questions or stating what I've done in the wrong manner.  I'm able to output the amount in words (as you can see from my result) but I believe the issue I am having lies somewhere in the user entering a Double and my code not including anything requesting <1000.00.  My main method does include the double number but each time I try to change the Int type in the moneyWord method to a Double the number Int in my If statements states that an int cannot be converted to a Double(which I know).  Also, I think my return statement may needs to include more information.  Again, I may be looking in the wrong direction for the error but I believe this is where I'm going wrong.  In addition, I think some of this material may be taught in future classes as I had to look into chapters in my textbook that have not yet been covered - namely Arrays.  Here is my code.  Any assistance would be appreciated

```
//program to write the word equivalent of a check amount
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CheckToWord {
    public static void main(String[] args) { // main method
        double number = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the check amount:"); // prompt user to enter check amount
        number = scanner.nextDouble();

        if (number == 0) {
            System.out.print("Zero");
        } else {
            System.out.print("" + moneyWord((int) number)); // output amount in words
        }
    }

    private static String moneyWord(int number) {
        String words = ""; // variable to hold string representation of number
        String onesArray[] = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten",
                "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" };
        String tensArray[] = { "zero", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty",
                "ninety" };

        if (number < 0) { // convert the number to a string
            String numberStr = "" + number;
            numberStr = numberStr.substring(1); // remove minus before the number
            return "minus " + moneyWord((int) Double.parseDouble(numberStr)); // add minus before the number and convert
                                                                                // the rest of number
        }

        if ((number / 1000) > 0) { // check if number is divisible by 1 thousand
            words += moneyWord(number / 1000) + " thousand ";
            number %= 1000;
        }

        if ((number / 100) > 0) { // check if number is divisible by a hundred
            words += moneyWord(number / 100) + " hundred ";
            number %= 100;
        }

        if (number < 20) { // check if number is within the teens
            words += onesArray[number]; // get the appropriate value from ones array
        } else {
            words += tensArray[number / 10]; // get the appropriate value from tens array
            if ((number % 10) > 0) {
                words += "-" + onesArray[number % 10];
            }
        }
        return words;
    }
}
```

Result

```
Please enter the check amount:
1523.23
one thousand five hundred twenty-three
```

Comment: OK, so if I understand correctly, you have a compilation error. Post the code containing the error. Post the exact and complete error message from the compiler. Tell whic line of code the error message refers to. Also, explain why you ask for a double if you want an int. And why you want an int if the goal is to translate a dcimal number.

Comment: 1523.23 is an invalid input as the value should be less than $1000.00

Comment: @MartínZaragoza Thank you for such a quick reply.  I want to now go back to replicate the errors so that I can post them.  I was aware that my input was over $1000.00 but I think I may need to state that the user only input an amount less than $1k. I will also try your input that you posted to my code. Stay tuned.

Comment: Great. How did it go? does it work for you?

Comment: @JBNizet If I change int number in the moneyWord method to a Double, number in lines 45, 48, and 50 says "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Double to Int". But after reviewing what Martin posted there was more issues than that.  As I needed to revise all 3 methods of my code as well as an If statement.  As I mentioned earlier, there were some things that we have not yet covered that I was trying to figure out on my own, namely arrays and parse. Thanks again for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class CheckToWord {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  //main method
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the check amount:"); //prompt user to enter check amount

        double number = scanner.nextDouble();
        String[] parsed = parse(Double.toString(number));
        int main = Integer.parseInt(parsed[0]);
        int change = Integer.parseInt(parsed[1]);

        if (main == 0 && change == 0) {
            System.out.print("Zero");
        } else {
            String mwm = moneyWord(main);
            String mwc = moneyWord(change);
            System.out.println("" + mwm + " and " + mwc + " cents");
        }
    }

    private static String[] parse(String number) {
        String[] split = number.contains(".") ? number.split(Pattern.quote(".")) : new String[]{number, "00"};
        String main = split[0];
        String change = split[1].length() >= 2 ? split[1].substring(0, 2) :
                split[1].length() == 1 ? split[1] + "0" : "00";
        return new String[]{main, change};
    }

    private static String moneyWord(int number) {
        if(number > 1000) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number value should be less than 1000");
        }

        String words = "";  // variable to hold string representation of number
        String onesArray[] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six",
                "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve",
                "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen",
                "eighteen", "nineteen"};
        String tensArray[] = {"zero", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty",
                "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};


        if (number < 0) { // convert the number to a string
            String numberStr = "" + number;
            numberStr = numberStr.substring(1);  // remove minus before the number
            return "minus " + moneyWord((int) Double.parseDouble(numberStr));  // add minus before the number and convert the rest of number
        }

        if ((number / 1000) > 0) { // check if number is divisible by 1 thousand
            words += moneyWord(number / 1000) + " thousand ";
            number %= 1000;
        }

        if ((number / 100) > 0) { // check if number is divisible by a hundred
            words += moneyWord(number / 100) + " hundred ";
            number %= 100;
        }

        if (number < 20) { // check if number is within the teens
            words += onesArray[number]; // get the appropriate value from ones array
        } else {
            words += tensArray[number / 10]; // get the appropriate value from tens array
            if ((number % 10) > 0) {
                words += "-" + onesArray[number % 10];
            }
        }
        return words;
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
Please enter the check amount:
10.25
ten and twenty-five cents
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance.  I've got it to run.  As I mentioned in my comments above, I'm into territory that has not yet been covered in the class - arrays and parse. Struggling a bit as its an online class but it's starting to come along.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility for separating the change from the whole amount would be as follows.

```java
      double[] vals = { 22.45, 1222.0, 122, .97, 2900.98
      };
      for (double val : vals) {
         int whole = (int) val;

         // get remainder, multiply by 100 and add .5 to round up 
         // prior to casting.
         int change = (int) ((val % 1) * 100 + .5);
         // if change is 0, use xx in place
         System.out.printf("%7.2f : %5d and %s/100%n",
               val,
               whole,
               (change == 0) ? "xx"
                     : change + "");
      }
```